# Sequelize the nodejs throught model association

Tags: sql, node.js, associations, sequelize.js

I have tree models `User`, `Company` and `UserCompany`.
I have associations

```
        Company.belongsToMany(User, {
            as: 'users',
            through: {
                model: UserCompany,
                unique: false
            },
            onDelete: 'cascade'
        });

        User.belongsToMany(Company, {
            as: 'companies',
            through: {
                model: UserCompany,
                unique: false
            },
            onDelete: 'cascade'
        });
```

I am trying to query companies buy runing this code

```
sql.Company.findAll({
    where: query,
    include: [{model:sql.User, as:'users', attributes: ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email']}],
    order: sort,
    limit: limit,
    offset: offset
})
```

I have two elements of `UserCompany` with `CompanyId=10` and `UserId=50`, but query returns only one of them.
It returns array

```
{id: 10,
 ...,
 users: {
     id: 50,
     ...,
     UserCompany: {}
 }
}
```

So `UserCompany` is not array, it is just one element. But I want to get them all. 
How can I fix my association code?

Answer (score 0):

Your associations are right. The `UserCompany` property isn't supposed to be showing all of each user's `UserCompany` relationships -- it's just showing the one that got the user included in that query's results.

If what you're looking for is a list of companies associated with each user in the returned array, you can add an `include` for that:

```
Company.findAll({
    include: [{  
        model: User, 
        as: 'users', 
        attributes: ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email'], 

        // Add this
        include: [{  
            model: Company, 
            as: 'companies', 
            attributes: ['id', 'name'] 
        }], 
    }],
})
```

This gives you the following format in the returned array:

```
{
  id: 1,
  first_name: 'Nelson',
  last_name: 'Bighetti',
  email: 'bighead@hooli.com',
  UserCompany: {...},
  companies: [
    { id: 1, name: 'Hooli', UserCompany: {...} },
    { id: 2, name: 'Pied Piper', UserCompany: {...} }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you help, but I am afraid my question was not clear. Now I edited it. If it is possible can you help me with this one, please.

Comment: Still not sure I understand. You have two duplicate `UserCompany` entries that link the same company and user?